# How to remove "Pandas" objects name from itertuples?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [0.1, 0.2]},
                      index=['a', 'b'])
```

Then:

```
tuples = list(df.itertuples(index=False))
tuples
```

Nevertheless, I noted that the tuples have the `"Pandas"` name. Despite I look at the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html#pandas.DataFrame.itertuples) for the parameters of `itertuples`, I didn't found how to remove it.

```
[Pandas(col1=1, col2=0.10000000000000001),
 Pandas(col1=2, col2=0.20000000000000001)]
```

I tried to put `name=''`. However, it removed the `col1=1` and `col2=2` names, which I need. Any idea of how to remove them, in order to have something more informative like this:

```
[(col1=1, col2=0.10000000000000001),
 (col1=2, col2=0.20000000000000001)]
```

Comment: What is desired output? list of tuples? There are also `=` ?

Comment: thanks for the help @jezrael. I updated the question!

Answer (score 3):

a `namedtuple` needs a name... event with the `collections` module you can't create a `namedtuple` without a name:

```
import collections
collections.namedtuple('Person', 'name age gender')
Out[6]: __main__.Person
```

now without a name

```
 In[7]: collections.namedtuple('', 'name age gender')
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2885, in run_code
        exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
      File "<ipython-input-7-12b9f81e7899>", line 1, in <module>
        collections.namedtuple('', 'name age gender')
      File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\collections.py", line 343, in namedtuple
        if name[0].isdigit():
```

long answer short, if you want the col name, you need a `namedtuple` and a `namedtuple` needs a name.

if you don't want a name, then use regular `tuple` but regular `tuple` doesn't have 'col' argument

so calling `df.itertuples()` returns `namedtuple` and calling `df.itertuples(index=False, name=None)` return regular `tuple`

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
tuples = list(df.itertuples(index=False, name=None))
```

Please note the document:

> name : string, default “Pandas”
>   The name of the returned namedtuples or **None to return regular tuples**.

More edited:
I don't think you can get print of results:

```
[(col1=1, col2=2)]
```

As documents of [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) states that `Pandas(col1=1, col2=2)` is a namedtuple, where `Pandas` is the `typename` of this namedtuple. When you print it out, it will print out the `typename`.

For your application, if you just try to iterate dataframe through itertuple way, both of `namedtuple` and regular `tuple` works, you can ignore the `Panda` name.

Comment: The OP already tried this, this removes the column names also which is not what OP wants